# Tricky calculation refresh based on columns using Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

Logic is to add the value in the new_r_aa after the first line of code output under 'aa_cumul'  Example, the code will take 3 (which is the first output  under 'aa_cumul') and sum it with the value 8 under the 'new_r_aa' column. This will result in  3+8 = 11   11+9=20, 20+ 8=28, 28+8=36 and so on. But remember the first groupby row should be unaffected and unchanged from the original input.

**Data**

```
data = {
    'city': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'CA'],
    'ID': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA'],
    'quarter': ['2024Q1', '2024Q2', '2024Q3', '2024Q4', '2025Q1', '2024Q1'],
    'cml_bb_racks': [6, 13, 18, 20, 30, 5],
    'r_aa_bx': [0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1],
    'cml_aa_bx': [1, 3, 6, 10, 12, 2],
    'BB_AA_Bx_Ratio': [6.0, 4.333333, 3.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5],
    'expected_aa_bx_delta': [1.81, 2.856537, 2.395498, 0.0, 2.1, 2.0],
    'total aa': [1.810000, 4.856537, 5.395498, 4.000000, 4.100000, 3.000000],
    'total round aa': [2.0, 6.0, 6.0, 4.0, 6.0, 4.0],
    'new_r_aa': [2.0, 8.0, 9.0, 8.0, 8.0, 5.0],
    'aa_cumul': [3.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 0.0, 6.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Desired**

```
data = {
    'city': ['NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'NY', 'CA'],
    'ID': ['AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA', 'AA'],
    'quarter': ['2024Q1', '2024Q2', '2024Q3', '2024Q4', '2025Q1', '2024Q1'],
    'cml_bb_racks': [6, 13, 18, 20, 30, 5],
    'r_aa_bx': [0, 2, 3, 4, 2, 1],
    'cml_aa_bx': [1, 3, 6, 10, 12, 2],
    'BB_AA_Bx_Ratio': [6.0, 4.333333, 3.0, 2.0, 2.5, 2.5],
    'expected_aa_bx_delta': [1.81, 2.856537, 2.395498, 0.0, 2.1, 2.0],
    'total aa': [1.800000, 4.856537, 5.395498, 4.000000, 4.100000, 3.000000],
    'total round aa': [2, 6, 6, 4, 6, 4],
    'new_r_aa': [2.0, 8.0, 9.0, 8.0, 8.0, 5.0],
    'aa_cumul': [3.0, 11.0, 20.0, 28.0, 36.0, 6.0]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
```

**Doing**

```
df['aa_cumul'] = df.groupby(['city', 'ID'])['new_r_aa'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().add(x.iloc[0])).fillna(df['new_r_aa'])
```

However, this code is not applying the correct reset. Any suggestion is helpful.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understood your update criteria. "Example, the code will take 3 (which is the first output under 'aa_cumul') and sum it with the value 8 under the 'new_r_aa' column. This will result in 3+8 = 11 and so on". I don't see any "8" in the new_r_aa column. How exactly are you getting the desired aa_cumul column?

Comment: updating now -pls check @SurajShourie

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC, the below code will get you your desired output:

```
df['aa_cumul'] = df.groupby(['city', 'ID'])['new_r_aa'].transform(lambda x: x.cumsum().add(-x.iloc[0])) + df.groupby(['city', 'ID'])['aa_cumul'].cumsum()
```

The first part basically does the cumusum for the 'new_r_aa' column without the first entry used and the second part just adds the existing value of aa_cumul to that. Assuming aa_cumul has all zeros except the first element

Output:

```
0     3.0
1    11.0
2    20.0
3    28.0
4    36.0
5     6.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: ok it makes sense - how would I add the other columns in @Suraj
Do I do df[''] = ? thanks

Comment: I didn't understand your question. Can you elaborate?

Comment: ok, how would I make this look exactly like my desired? (including the columns from original dataset)

Comment: Oh okay, just do `df['aa_cumul'] = ... `. Edited my answer